# What should I make money for?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm currently level 49 with my Altmer Battlemage and have about 75k of gold. I'd like to know whether there is any sense in saving my money.

Is there anything *really* expensive in the game on higher levels? Will I need the money for crafting dragon armor?  May I need it for crafting? Is there anything challenging I can try with my money where I have the risk of losing it?

Comment: Why were the tags "the elder scrolls" and "pc" removed?! The game is part of the elder scrolls series and I'm playing it on PC which is important to know because people might like to know whether I can use console or not - which is only possible on PC.

Comment: Exa, there is a movement to cut down on excess tags, see the meta about it. The pc tag is irrelevant, even if you are not able to use the console commands, others with similar problems might be. So lets always give console command answers :D.

Comment: "have about 75k gold". You ARE the 1%. #richguyproblems

Comment: The PC tag was removed because this is not a question limited specifically to that version of the game so people who play on the xbox or ps3 can also benefit from this question. The elder scrolls tag was removed because while this game is from that series the question is specifically for the version found in Skyrim.

Comment: @ids ... 75k is not much.

Comment: @Exa, don't own the game, so I wouldn't know. Did play a lot of oblivion, where 75k was enough to get most of the stuff you need. Unless you went for 100% completion, got all the houses, invested in all the shops etc.

Comment: @Ids It is currently enough to afford most of the stuff, but it's not hard to get. I just played the game and didn't do extensive investments or something like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only really expensive items in the game are the houses that you can purchase and upgrade in the major holds.  Even if you haven't purchased any of them yet, your 75,000 in gold is plenty to buy them all.

Have you purchased all the spells that you want from the teachers at the Mage's College?  Again, you'll come nowhere close to burning through 75K of gold.

Finally, having a decent chunk of gold is useful as an investment fund for leveling your smithing/enchanting.  You can buy large amounts of animal skins, iron ingots, soul gems, etc.  Craft a bunch of equipment and throw enchantments on them to level up.  In the vanilla game, you'll typically make back more than your original investment when you're reselling in the enchanted gear, assuming you can find enough merchants with enough funds to buy them all.  As before, 75K is WAY more than enough to get this going.

Short answer, you've got plenty of money, don't worry that you'll waste it in some way.

Answer (score 10):

If you are playing on PC and using the Steam version there is an achievement for having 100k gold.

Comment: Is there a non-Steam version available on PC?

Answer (score 6):

Paying teachers is what I spent the majority of my gold on. 75k can be spent pretty fast if you're at a high skill level and train 5 times each player level.